# Export VM as a OVF file from VMware Fusion

Tags: vmware-fusion

I am currently running VMware Fusion 6 on 10.9. I know that in ESX, and I believe even VMware Workstation, you can export a VM to a OVF file and redeploy on VirtualBox, VMware Workstaion/Fusion, and ESX.

My question is, is there a way I can make a OVF file on Fusion for the VM I want to deploy or am I out of luck?

Answer (score 18):

```
cd /Applications/VMware\ Fusion.app/Contents/Library/VMware\ OVF\ Tool/

./ovftool  <PATH TO SOURCE VM's .vmx file>   <PATH TO OUTPUT ova file>

# example

./ovftool --acceptAllEulas ~/Documents/Virtual\ Machines.localized/CentOS\ 6.5.vmwarevm/CentOS\ 6.5.vmx      /tmp/CentOS6.5.ova
```

Comment: for Fusion 8. `sudo ln -sf /Applications/VMware\ Fusion.app/Contents/Library/VMware\ OVF\ Tool/ovftool /usr/local/bin/`

Comment: If your virtual machine has a `.vmwarevm` extension you need to reference the `.vmx` file inside when using ovf tool. Right click on the virtual machine and select 'Show Package Contents'. Inside you will find the `.vmx` file to reference with ovf tool.

Answer (score 13):

./ovftool --acceptAllEulas /Users/admin/Documents/Virtual Machines.localized/IDM.vmwarevm/IDM.vmx ~/Users/admin/Documents/IDM.ova

Comment: --acceptAllEulas   eq  Accepts all end user license agreement's, Then you provide path of the .vmx /.ova file to create. This process will take some time.

Comment: my files have extension -- .vmwarevm and it gives this error - Opening OVF source:xyz.vmwarevm.ovf
Error: Failed to open OVF descriptor
Completed with errors

Comment: You need to reference the `.vmx` file inside the `.vmwarevm` package. On Mac, right click on your virtual machine and select 'Show Package Contents'. Inside you will find the `.vmx` file that you need to reference with ovf tool.

Answer (score 2):

If you have upgraded VMware Fusion, you can export ova in GUI. As of VMware Fusion 7.1.3, you can do this in File->Export to OVF, like [this.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZsA8a.png)

Comment: This does provide an answer. He has explained how to do it and provided a link for corroboration.

Comment: I believe you must be using VMware Fusion Pro.  My just-upgraded version to 8.0 does not have a File -> Export to OVF option.

Comment: Thank you for pointing this out.  To anyone else having troubles an immediate fix may be to download a trial of vmware fusion 10 pro, which does have export built into the file menu. Saved the day for me.

Answer (score 0):

Download the appropriate [installer from VMware's site](https://my.vmware.com/group/vmware/details?downloadGroup=OVFTOOL410&productId=491)

For my OSX setup, rather than the convoluted white spaced pathing to the tool, I created a symlink so my $PATH could pick it up

`sudo ln -s /Applications/VMware\ OVF\ Tool/ovftool /usr/local/bin/ovftool`

And then ran ovftool like [marathon](https://stackoverflow.com/users/356011/marathon)